# Which methods return jQuery objects?

Tags: methods, jquery

`$(this).hasClass('something')` returns a boolean value.

Q: Is there a list of which methods return non jQuery objects?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you call a method, you call it for a reason.

If you called the method to find something out (eg, `hasClass`, `is`, `index`, `filter`, etc), it will return that value.
If you called the method to do something (eg, `animate`, `load`, `append`, etc), it will return the original jQuery object.

Note that "property" methods (eg, `val`, `html`, `css`, `width`, etc) will fall into different categories depending on how you call them.

For more details, check the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com).

Comment: Yeah, I knew it would be a hard question to ask.  I thank you for sending me to the documentation.
Maybe I can ask it another way....  Is there a grid where column A is the method name and column B is the type of return value one can expect?  I understand that the answer for "property" methods would be "it depends", but maybe there's a better way to quickly summarize these methods.  In the old days, this was called a tan card and every programmer would walk around with one in his back pocket.  Today they are called cheat sheets and sold at Barnes & Noble.

Comment: My point is that if you're calling the method, you _already_ know what it returns.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the [jQuery API reference](http://docs.jquery.com/Main_Page) should provide this info.

Comment: Thanks spender for sending me to the documentation.
Is there a summary somewhere?  Something like a list of the methods and their return types?
I'm envisioning a spreadsheet where the programmer can filter and sort.